# Add event listener in javascript for IE 7

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I want to make list of menu by using images. Each menu has two images (filename.jpg & filename_active.jpg). Everytime i put the mouse over its image, the image will change to the other one. It works okay in Firefox and chrome, but i have problems in IE 7 and lower. 
The problem is, javascript will only read the last part (in this case, he will read third menu only). 
The code that i will show below is only part of javascript code for in IE.
Let me show my code :

HTML :

```
<ul>
<li class="caresoul_menu active" id="menuli_first"><a href="first.php"><img src="img_first_active.jpg" /></a></li>
<li class="caresoul_menu" id="menuli_two"><a href="two.php"><img src="img_two.jpg" /></a></li>
<li class="caresoul_menu" id="menuli_three"><a href="three.php"><img src="img_three.jpg" /></a></li>
```

Javascript :

```
var caresoul_menu = Dom.getElementsByClassName('caresoul_menu', 'li');
if(caresoul_menu.length > 0) {
   for(var im in caresoul_menu) {
      if (caresoul_menu[im].attachEvent) {
         caresoul_menu[im].attachEvent('onmouseover', function(){
            var liId = caresoul_menu[im].getAttribute('id').split('menuli_')[1];
            caresoul_menu[im].firstChild.firstChild.setAttribute('src','/image/'+liId+'_active.png');
         })
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use something like Prototype or jQuery?

Comment: You are using the iteration variable (`im`) of an iteration loop that has finished. Since the `Function` that is attached to the list `Element` will not always use that same value, you will only have the desired effect on the last Element.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain: when the mouseover event is fired, the `for` loop has already ended so the `im` variable has the last known value and the value is the same for all `<li>` elements. Try something like:

```
  if (caresoul_menu[im].attachEvent) {
     (function (that) {
        that.attachEvent('onmouseover', function(){
           var liId = that.getAttribute('id').split('menuli_')[1];
           that.firstChild.firstChild.setAttribute('src','/image/'+liId+'_active.png');
        });
     })(caresoul_menu[im]);
  }
```

Do you *really* need to use `attachEvent`? If you'd attach event listeners the DOM0 way (`element.onmouseover = function(){}`), you could use the `this` keyword in the event listener.

Comment: Duri, you're completely right. when the mouseover event is fired, the for loop has already ended. I tried your code and it's working now. Thanks,